# How can @Transactional annotation change the order of results from API call - Spring?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a test method annotated with @Transactional because I want to run the next tests if the present test will failed.

But when I extract data from API call from my database in test method annotated with @Transactional I have sometime different order of object even if in API I sort my result by date of added.

Exit another best alternative for @Transactional or a solution for this problem?

P.S. I use DateTime for my added date and I expect to this fact influence the result by convert to GMT.

Comment: That is not easy to answer. APIs normally don't load in any order, but the service behind them. Is this Service also transactional, does it sort in memory or by using order by. What do you mean by order, do you return a list, a set, a collection. Do you use JPA to load? I think it would be best, to give a simple code example.

Comment: I use JPA Repository to return a list. And in my test I produce 3 objects for save and all test run just 1 second and the update date are the same for all object. So, I think my JPA have need another sort argument near added date. Exist any solution?

Comment: Once more, perhaps some of your code would tell much more than your description. There are to many open questions. For instance, how do you expect a sort order if all dates are the same?